# Let $0\le a\le b\le c$ be real numbers. Prove that $(a+3b)(b+4c)(c+2a)\ge60abc$

Tags: inequality

Let $0\le a\le b\le c$ be real numbers. Prove that $(a+3b)(b+4c)(c+2a)\ge60abc$

My attempt:

By AM-GM inequaltiy, we get,

$a+3b\ge 4a^{\frac14}b^{\frac34}$
$b+4c\ge 5b^{\frac15}c^{\frac45}$
$c+2a\ge 3c^{\frac13}a^{\frac23}$

Multiplying we get,
$(a+3b)(b+4c)(c+2a)\ge 60 a^{\frac14+\frac23}b^{\frac15+\frac34}c^{\frac13+\frac45}$

So, I get something which is different from what I need. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You nearly have it, just use $c^{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{4}{5}}\ge c\cdot b^{\frac{1}{20}}\cdot a^{\frac{1}{12}}$, which follows from $c\ge b\ge a\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Let $b = a+x, c = b+y = a+x+y$,and reduce. Note $x, y \geq 0$.

$LHS = (a+3a+3x)(a+x+4a+4x+4y)(a+x+y+2a) = (4a+3x)(5a+5x+4y)(3a+x+y)$. Do the same for $RHS$ and compare and probably complete square...Expand this product.

Comment: Cannot think of how that will help. Will you elaborate please?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the sum of the powers is one. Therefore:

$$60 a^{\frac14+\frac23}b^{\frac15+\frac34}c^{\frac13+\frac45}= 60 a^{\frac{11}{12}}b^{\frac{19}{20}}c^{\frac{17}{15}}$$

Now use the fact that 
$$c^{\frac{2}{15}}=c^{\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{20}} \geq a^{\frac{1}{12}} b^{\frac{1}{12}}$$